# Calculating which two yugioh decks are more likely to win?

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

Is there a computer program that can calculate mathematically which two Yugioh decks have a better probability of winning a match? Assuming that the cards in the two decks doesn't change, does the Central Limit theorem applies in approximating the probability that one deck will win?

Comment: This question assumes that card effects (including Monster effects) are NOT negligible.

Comment: Depending on the format, and how they manage infinite loops these days, you can probably show this is equivalent to the halting problem. I know MTG had a Turing machine combo... Just need to encode in some infinite loop a bunch of states. Likewise, it's probably easy to show that detecting a winning move can be arbitrarily hard.

Comment: I believe Kaiba has one.

Comment: How come you need infinite loop to solve this problem? And what makes detecting a winning move "arbitrarily hard"?